# Is it possible to add words to the iOS dictation dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, dictation

I am building an iOS app and it would be very nice if I could enable some custom words for the dictation feature (dictation when entering text into UITextView, etc) in addition to the existing dictionary.

In other words, I want some words that are not a part of Apple's dictation dictionary to be available when dictating text. I originally thought this was not possible, but I was hoping I could verify with the SO community.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.  This SO thread has some promising leads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419940/access-ios-dictionary-programmatically