# Programmatically expanding iOS dictionary app lexicons

Tags: ios, dictionary

There is an app in the Apple App Store that downloads custom dictionaries and programmatically adds them to the iOS's built-in Dictionary.app without user intervention. It works normally with the stock ROM, i.e. no jailbreak or anything of that sort is required.

I wonder how this is possible since Apple has never documented such a "feature." There is no API or  hints in the iOS and Dictionary.app documents to explain how this is done.

How could this be implemented?

Comment: 1. What "Dictionary.app"? There is no such app in iOS by default.
2. Which App Store app do you mean? We can't help you if you don't tell us the name of the app.

Comment: 1. The iOS built in Dictionary is the app that gets activated by selecting a word then choosing "Define" from the popup menu. See here: http://forums.imore.com/attachments/guides-how-articles/49391d1392595078t-guide-how-define-word-using-ios7-s-built-dictionary-step1.jpg

Comment: 2. The other app that I'm referring to, which could download and add custom dictionaries, is called "Dictionary.appender" and can be found here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dictionary.appender/id650562573?mt=8

Comment: @user3524743 You should look at any app in iOS 7.1 and you will see that the ability to add user shortcuts is now available by tapping and holding any selectable text and then clicking the Learn item in the context menu. This allows users to update the shortcut list which expands the user lexicon. Also clicking on Define in the same context menu will now show the dictionary where one can download all major dictionaries. This is built-in for free, you implement by adding a textview to an app and making it selectable.

Comment: @TommieC., application that we are talking about implements something that is not available in iOS SDK - downloading and adding custom dictionaries. The app does this using private APIs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dictionary.appender app uses private framework `MobileAsset.framework`. There are several selectors that the app use:

- `setQueriesLocalAssetInformationOnly:`
- `runQueryAndReturnError:`
- `initWithAssetType:attributes:`. Asset types are `com.apple.MobileAsset.DictionaryServices.dictionary` for iOS < 7 and `com.apple.MobileAsset.DictionaryServices.dictionary2` for iOS >= 7. They are saved in `/var/mobile/Library/Assets/`.

And here's class-dump of the framework https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework where you can find methods with those selectors.

In order to call them the app uses very simple technique - `NSClassFromString` to obtain class object in runtime. In our case, `ASAsset` and `ASAssetQuery` classes. I don't know how this got approved in App Store but that's how it works. Very simple technique , selectors and class names are not even encrypted.

**UPDATE**

The app doesn't explicitly link private `MobileAsset.framework`. It doesn't use any of the usual techniques to dynamically load a framework - no `dlopen` or `NSBundle` calls. Import table doesn't contain private `MobileAsset.framework` either. But it linked by `UIKit.framework` which obviously is linked by the app. I did a simple test. Wrote a stripped out console application that links only needed frameworks by turning off all the project settings that may automatically link the frameworks. Without `UIKit.framework` executing `NSClassFromString(@"ASAsset")` returns nil. With `UIKit.framework` it returns `ASAsset` class object.

Comment: This sounds good. I think the next step is to know how the app links that framework. So, will keep looking. Thank you creker.

Comment: Also, built-in Dictionary is not an app. It's just a view controller that's probably implemented in `UIKit` or some other framework. Just like `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update creker. It brings me or anyone looking to duplicate that functionality closer to the target.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to submit an app with similar functionality to the App Store if that is what you wanna do. Eventually Dictionary.appender will be removed. I don't understand how reviewers are so blind that they approved such an app but I hope they will remove it eventually.
If I answered your question then please accept the answer.

Comment: @creker how did you find this?

Comment: @Kayvan, analyzed disassembly

Comment: @creker thanks dude, that seems something really interesting :D. Googled it but did not find anything usefull, expect some book chapters. is there any other resource to learn more about that?