# Validate user entered English language word with dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

Note: This is not a duplicate Question: Other question's answer has a flaw i.e. `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` forces a view controller on you while I wanted to do the dictionary check in the background.

In my swift iPhone app, I want to check if the user entered word exists in Engligh language dictionary.

I am trying

```
let wordDefinition = DCSCopyTextDefinition(.....
```

to see if I get in return a non-nil (word is valid) or nil (invalid word)

but according to documentation it requires CoreServices framework which does not seem available to iOS (OSX only ?)

Am I on the right track and there is a way to check word definition in iOS (or better yet word validity) in English language dictionary or I will have to employ a 3rd party English language dictionary in my project?

Comment: One of the answers here (not the accepted one) says there's a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419940/access-ios-dictionary-programmatically

Comment: Thanks, I was able to download OSX dictionary