# How to create a custom list of words for predictive text

Tags: text

I am thinking about making an app to do with electrical equipment and I would like the app to recognise the name of tools as you write to save you time (predictive text). How would I go about creating a custom list of words the app recognises. Can anyone please point me in the right direction. I have looked around and not found much information on the subject. I am currently using objective c although learning swift so any of those languages will do. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not predictive text but rather *autocomplete*.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419940/access-ios-dictionary-programmatically), there's an answer by *Jano* with [a link to code](https://github.com/j4n0/trie-suggest) that seems to do what you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is useful and for what I've seen goes in the general direction of what I want to do, but with one difference: I don't want a dictionary, web or otherwise, I want the app to recognise certain photographic and electrical tools, that I have in a database so for example something like: "Interfit EXD200 Home Studio Kit", so when I start typing Inter... it will write the rest.

Comment: You will need a list of all the names of the tools that the autocomplete will work with, that's called a _dictionary_ of words/phrases.